# Selenium and Xpath - accessing elements adjacent to each other

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

In the example below I'm trying to click on **Follow Me** where the adjacent(ish) `<div>` is equal to **David**. This is one of many `<div class='_1m'` on the page all with the same structure.(does that make sense?)

Sorry first time posting a problem and a forgot one major detail. I know that I'm looking for David but I don't know what the 'Follow Me' Value will be. It changes on each record.

```
<div class="_1m">
  <div class="_8h"><img src="/2323.GIF" /></div>
  <div class="_1j">
    <div class="_1c">David<span class="_13">abc</span></div>
    <div>
      <span class="_1v">ABCD</span>
      <span class="_1v">1234</span>
    </div>
    <div>7890</div>
  </div>
  <div class="_3h">
    <div class="_n0">
      <span class="_bn"><span class="_la">Follow Me</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below xpath `//div[@class='_1c'][contains(.,'David')]/../following-sibling::div//span[@class='_la'][contains(.,'Follow Me')]`

Explaination:

1. `//div[@class='_1c'][contains(.,'David')]` loate the **David**
2. `/..` move to one parent node of David because follow me emement is sibling of that parent div
3. `/following-sibling::div` locate immediate following sibling div
4. `//span[@class='_la'][contains(.,'Follow Me')]` Loate the span which has Follow me text

Answer (score 2):

To click on **Follow Me** where the adjacent `<div>` contains the text **David** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *following*:

  ```
  //div[contains(., 'David')]//following::span[3]/span
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *following* and the *text* **Follow Me**:

  ```
  //div[contains(., 'David')]//following::span[3]/span[text()='Follow Me']
  ```